# SSRS subscription purgatory -- An error has occurred. Something went wrong. Please try again later

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

4 SSRS report subscriptions I created weeks ago were working fine until this past weekend our DBA upgraded our SQL Server instance to 2017.

The subscriptions were deleted. And worse, I'm unable to create new subscriptions because I keep encountering this error

> An error has occurred. Something went wrong. Please try again later.

I'm not certain that the upgrade caused the issue but I'm suspicious. Can someone please help me determine why I'm getting this cryptic message and how to fix it?

Side note: Downgrading the version is not an option.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a compatibility issue. The way i fixed the problem was deleting the associated reports, re-deploying the reports and re-creating the subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed a similar issue - the problem was an apostrophe in the report name. I removed the report from the catalog and data source tables in the ReportServer database and uploaded a new copy with the corrected name.